# jquery hover flip effect on hyperlink

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, hover

Does anyone know if there is a jquery plugin to accomplish an hover effect on a hyperlink like it's done on this site (right top corner, social network links) http://www.julesbassoleil.fr/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an icon-sprite as you can see here:

http://www.julesbassoleil.fr/img/social_icons.png

The only thing you have to do is setting the correct background positions with css on load and animate the background position on hover with jquery.

Comment: thank you, you are right. It works gread with these technique.